# instancia continua rodando mesmo depois de fechada por uma thread

Tags: java, thread

Bom mesmo após fechar minha instancia ela continua rodando por conta de uma thread que eu criei para chamar um while:

```
public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(event.getKeyCode()));
        if (event.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_BACKQUOTE) {
            keepPressingO = true;
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        while (keepPressingO) {
                             Robot robot = new Robot();
                             robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
                             Thread.sleep(26);
                             robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
                             robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
                             Thread.sleep(16);
                             robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_W);
                             robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E);
                             Thread.sleep(26);
                             robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_E);
                        }

                    } catch (AWTException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }.start();

        }

        if (event.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_ENTER) {
            keepPressingO = false;
        }

    }
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar como eu resolvo essa situação?
Como eu conseguiria por a thread para dormir quando ela sair do while ( e se voltasse pro if ela acordaria?)

E como eu conseguiria chamar essa thread dentro de um windowClosing para matar ela?

Answer (score 0):

tenta criar essa thread fora desse escopo la na declaração de variáveis da classe, e por fim para finaliza-la tente o metodo join().